# I need my batch file to execute 3 files at the same time - wait for them to finish - then move on to send the email

Tags: batch-file

Here's what I've got:

```
START 1_0.bat
START 1_0_1.bat
START  1_0_2.bat


START /w sendEmail -f blaahg@gmail.com -t blahg@gmail.com .....
```

Anyway,
I want it to simulataneously execute the first three items (which it is)  then wait for all of them to complete - then execute the last email step.  It's currently not waiting to execute the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REM start the processes, giving them a "unique" title:
START "MyProcess1" 1_0.bat
START "MyProcess2" 1_0_1.bat
START "MyProcess3" 1_0_2.bat
:loop
  timeout /t 1 >nul
  REM check if a task with the "unique" title is still running:
  tasklist /v|find "MyProcess">nul && goto :loop
echo all tasks have finished.
```

`&&` works as "if previous command (`find`) was successful, then...

Comment: It's pretty taxing on my system but it's totally working - thank you much!

Comment: the loop itself should eat nealy no perfomance (that's what the `timeout` is  for). But I can't speak for your bat files, as I don't know them.

Answer (score 0):

Best to put these into another batch file like  step1.bat

Step1.bat

```
START 1_0.bat
START 1_0_1.bat
START  1_0_2.bat
```

Then in your main have

```
START /wait step1.bat

START /w sendEmail -f          blaahg@gmail.com -t      blahg@gmail.com .....
```

Comment: This method don't works. The `Step1.bat` file ends as soon as the three `START` commands are executed and don't waits for the Batch files themselves...

Answer (score 0):

You may use a file as *flag* to indicate that a given Batch file is running. Create a flag file for each running Batch file and remove it before each Batch file ends:

```
echo X > 1_0.flg
START 1_0.bat
echo X > 1_0_1.flg
START 1_0_1.bat
echo X > 1_0_2.flg
START  1_0_2.bat

rem Wait for all previous Batch files to end
:wait
if exist *.flg goto wait

START /w sendEmail -f blaahg@gmail.com -t blahg@gmail.com .....
```

And remove the flag file in each one of the Batch files this way:

```
del "%~N0.flg"
```

... or directly writing the name of each Batch file in the DEL command.

You may also insert a `ping -n 2 localhost > NUL` command in the `:wait` cycle in order to not spend too much CPU in the wait cycle. Increment the `2` value if you wish.